# Possible bug in Html.DropDownList, selected values not reflecting?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-3

I know this has been asked a few times before, but the existing solutions look like hacks rather than a proper pattern.

I have a simple drop down list. I am trying to populate it with data and have a item pre selected. I am succeeding at the 'populate it with data part' but failing to get my preferred item pre-selected.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2.

The important code bits:

```
{
    // Bunch of code
    CategoryOptions = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Slug", article.Category.Id);
}
```

Now... the CategoryOptions is being passed to the Html helper like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Category, Model.CategoryOptions)
```

I have looked at the values being passed into the helper and have confirmed that one of the items has the selected value set to true:

[image]

However, it is not reflecting in the Html being generated by the helper. None of the ... tags have the selected="selected" attribute.

I used Reflector to examine the code a bit, and this line (SelectExtensions.SelectInternal) looks dicey:

```
item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? set.Contains(item.Value) : set.Contains(item.Text);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is the framework (ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2) at fault here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I just fixed it.

I changed around my view model to use a CategoryId instead of a Category slug. So now, my view looks like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.CategoryId, Model.CategoryOptions, new { @class = "ask-category-field" })
```

I think the model value being select (in this case, a => a.CategoryId) has to have the same type as the selected 'value.' (I will refine this explanation when I get more time to go over the framework code.) But clever coding indeed :) Hats of to ASP.NET MVC devs.

Now, it works perfectly as expect and also retains changes to the selected item across a PRG lifecycle.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The selected property on a dropdown item doesn't actually set the dropdown item to be selected in the HTML.

I've experienced this problem myself before.

My solution to this was an extension method on the `ViewDataDictionary` that allows you to set the value of a given select list based on the selected item & a string Id of the select list.

```
public static void SetSelectedValueFor(this ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary, string key, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items)
        {
            //  HACK: Store the selected item value in ViewData so that the DropDownListFor knows which one should be selected.
            //  It's a bit of a hack but it seems to be the only way I can do it since DropdownListFor ignores the Selected property on SelectListItem.
            var x = items.Where(c => c.Selected).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)
            {
                viewDataDictionary[key] = x.Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... I also posted the answer which I found out minutes after posting the question. Hope this helps you too.